# Same name of a file scope variable and a function parameter in C possible. Possible to distinguish?

Tags: c

Is it possible to distinguish between file scope variable and function parameter in C, like in C++ using the this keyword?

I wonder if it is possible to do this in C somehow:

**.c:**

```
static int X;

void Foo(int X)
{
    //How to do line below?
    fileScopeX = functionParameterX;
}
```

Comment: You can't distinguish between local and global variables in C++ with `this` either - you can distinguish between local and instance variables that way.

Comment: Is there some C "replacement"? I did not make it clear =/

Comment: No, but you can enable shadow warnings with `gcc -Wshadow`

Answer (score 2):

There is one nasty trick:

```
void Foo(int x)
{
    int y;
    {
        extern int x;
        y = x;  /* This refers to the x from the outside. */
    }
}
```

---

I just noticed the outer x is `static`. In that case the compiler won't allow the inner `extern int x`.

Comment: I have updated my question as I was not clear with the terminology. I want to assign a file scope variable the value of a function parameter that have the same name.

Comment: Does you edit mean that this is not possible when it is file scope instead of global?

Comment: @Phataas I think we mean the same thing, yes.